# Search all of my info files

Tags: info, manual

In GNU Emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 17.10, `emacs -Q`:

`(info "(gnus) The Gnus Registry")` finds the right page.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `info-apropos` <kbd>RET</kbd> `gnus registry` <kbd>RET</kbd> finds nothing.

Is there a command I can use to search *all* of my info files?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is because `info-apropos` *searches the* **indexes** of each manual, and in the Gnus manual there is no index entry that matches `gnus registry`. (However, if you ask it to look for `gnus-registry`, with a hyphen, it finds search hits.) Perhaps `info-apropos` should automatically include general terms associated with each particular manual, e.g., include `gnus` for the Gnus manual. You can submit an enhancement request using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: `C-h f index-apropos` tells you that it looks for a *string* in the indexes. It does *not* do "apropos" (e.g., keyword or regexp) matching. Maybe it should. Or maybe it's name should be changed to not suggest that it does. Again: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a command that does the job.  It uses the core of `info-apropos`, substituting the regular apropos handling of input.

I've now added this to [Info+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPlus) ([`info+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/info%2b.el)), as a redefinition of standard command `info-apropos`.  This also uses another window, if you're not already in Info.

```el
(defun my-info-apropos (pattern &optional literalp)
  "Search indexes of all known Info files on your system for apropos PATTERN.
Build a menu of the possible matches.

With a prefix arg, match PATTERN as a literal string, not as a regexp
or keywords.

Just as for commands such as `apropos', PATTERN can be a word, a list
of words (separated by spaces), or a regexp (using some regexp special
characters).  If it is a word, search for matches for that word as a
substring.  If it is a list of words, search for matches for any
two (or more) of those words."
  (interactive (list (apropos-read-pattern "index entries") current-prefix-arg))
  (apropos-parse-pattern pattern)
  (if (equal apropos-regexp "")
      (Info-find-node Info-apropos-file "Top")
    (let ((nodes  Info-apropos-nodes)
          nodename)
      (while (and nodes  (not (string-match apropos-regexp (nth 1 (car nodes)))))
        (setq nodes  (cdr nodes)))
      ;; Use another window, if not already in Info.
      (unless (eq major-mode 'Info-mode) (pop-to-buffer "*info*"))
      (if nodes
          (Info-find-node Info-apropos-file (caar nodes))
        (setq nodename  (format "Index for ‘%s’" apropos-regexp))
        (push (list nodename
                    apropos-regexp
                    (Info-apropos-matches apropos-regexp (and (not literalp) 'REGEXP)))
              Info-apropos-nodes)
        (Info-find-node Info-apropos-file nodename)))))
```

You'll also need to modify `Info-apropos-matches` (or define another function that is the modified version, and call that in the code above), so that it accepts an optional arg `REGEXP-P`, which if non-`nil` does *not* `regexp-quote` the `STRING` arg. In other words, replace the use of just `STRING` with `(if REGEXP-P STRING (regexp-quote STRING))`.

I submitted Emacs [bug #31807](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31807) for this.